# Uneven printout on the right sight of the page

Tags: laser-printer, toner, color-printer

Recently I noticed a problem with color printouts on my Samsung CLP-315 color laser printer. On the right side of the page there are very noticeable stripes in the printout:

[image: printout with uneven color on the right side]

I'm not really sure where to approach the problem. I tried replacing the cyan toner (since I already have a spare one at home) but it didn't make any difference.

What could be the reason for such a printout? How can I try resolving it?

Comment: What direction is it printing out?  Starts clear to finishing with the hatching, hatching to clear, cyan to black or black to cyan?  It'll help figure out why.

Comment: @BrianDaniels It's printing from cyan to black.